# Aspect method interception over a Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-aop, aspect

I have a Spring mvc controller with to methods:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/method1", method = GET) 
public A method1() throws Exception 
{           
    return new A();
}
```

and

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/method2", method = GET) 
public int method2() throws Exception 
{           
    return -1;
}
```

I want to intercept these methods with an Aspect:

```
@Before("execution(** com.test.controller.*(..))")
public void startLog()
{
    System.out.println("START");
}
```

This aspect works ok with `method1` and fails with `method2`. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pointcut expression for methods in a particular package having @RequestMapping annotation:

```
@Before("execution(* com.test.controller.*.*(..)) && @annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping)")
    public void startLog()
    {
        System.out.println("START");
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I had an error with the double ** as a returned type. With this and the annotation it works ok. Thanks